# Align ouput text to the right with cout

Tags: c++, output, iomanip

In my program I would like to display status messages like so

```
Checking system               [OK]
Loading required files        [OK]
...
```

But right now its comes like the following when I use `\t`

```
Checking system        [OK]
Loading required files        [OK]
```

I tried setw but it comes like (probably because of bad implementation)

```
           Checking system[OK]
    Loading required files[OK]
```

So is there a way I can format the output WITHOUT using any external libraries (ie, no ncurses etc)

Also note that the size of the output terminal is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::left` to display a string left-justified in a specified width of field:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(30) << "Checking system";
```